# Markov chain, Q matrix, jump matrix and invariant distribution

Tags: markov-chains

For the following Q matrix i want to find the jump matrix and the invariant distribution.
\[
Q= \begin{pmatrix}
  -2 &1 &1 &0\\
   2    &  -4 &1 &1\\
   1 &0 &-1 &0\\
   1 &1 &0 &-2
\end{pmatrix}\]
I can find the jump matrix but am not sure how to find invariant distribution. Is it the same as discrete case?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Solve $\mu^TQ=0$ (instead of $m^TP=m$ in the discrete time case).

Comment: Thanks i'll try this as well to see if it comes out the same

Comment: You know what? It does.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\Id{\operatorname{Id}}$Computing the invariant distribution can be down in three steps:

1. Compute (as you allready did), the jump matrix $S$ (in the following $D$ will denote $Q$s diagonal part).
   \[ S = \Id - D^{-1}Q = \Id - 
   \begin{pmatrix}
     1 &-\frac 12 &-\frac 12 &0\\
     -\frac 12    &  1 &-\frac 14 &-\frac 14\\
      -1 &0 &1 &0\\
      -\frac 12 &-\frac 12&0 &1
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0 &\frac 12 &\frac 12 &0\\
     \frac 12    &  0 &\frac 14 &\frac 14\\
      1 &0 &0 &0\\
      \frac 12 &\frac 12&0 &0
   \end{pmatrix}
   \]
2. Compute a right eigenvector $\varphi$ of $S$ for the eigenvalue 1, that is $\varphi$ fulfills $\varphi = \varphi S$, we will find $\varphi^t$, $S^t -\Id$ equals 
   \begin{align*}
      \begin{pmatrix}
     -1    &\frac 12 & 1 & \frac 12\\
     \frac 12    &  -1 &0 &\frac 12\\
      \frac 12&\frac 14 &-1 &0\\
      0 &\frac 14&0 &-1
   \end{pmatrix} &\leadsto
      \begin{pmatrix}
     -1    &\frac 12 & 1 & \frac 12\\
     1     &  -2 &0 &1\\
      1&\frac 12 &-2 &0\\
      0 &\frac 14&0 &-1
   \end{pmatrix} \\
   &\leadsto
      \begin{pmatrix}
     -1    &\frac 12 & 1 & \frac 12\\
     0     &  -\frac 32 &1 &\frac 32\\
      0&1 &-1 &\frac 12\\
      0 &\frac 14&0 &-1
   \end{pmatrix} \\
   &\leadsto
      \begin{pmatrix}
     -1    &\frac 12 & 1 & \frac 12\\
      0&1 &-1 &\frac 12\\
     0     &  -3 &2 &3\\
      0 &1&0 &-4
   \end{pmatrix} \\
   &\leadsto
      \begin{pmatrix}
     -1    &\frac 12 & 1 & \frac 12\\
      0&1 &-1 &\frac 12\\
     0     &  0 &-1 &\frac 92\\
      0 &0&1 &-\frac 92
   \end{pmatrix} \\
   &\leadsto
      \begin{pmatrix}
     -1    &\frac 12 & 1 & \frac 12\\
      0&1 &-1 &\frac 12\\
     0     &  0 &-1 &\frac 92\\
      0 &0& 0 &0
   \end{pmatrix} \\
   \end{align*}
   So a eigenvector is given by $\varphi = (14, 8,9 , 2)$.
3. The stationary distribution is then given by $\pi := -\frac{\varphi D^{-1}}{\|\varphi D^{-1}\|_1}$. We have $\varphi D^{-1} = (-7, -2, -9, -1)$, so $\|\varphi D^{-1}\|_1 = 19$, that is 
   \[ \pi = \frac 1{19}(7, 2, 9, 1). \]

Comment: What have you defined lower case d as?

Comment: $\operatorname{Id}$ denotes the Identity.